# Postfix different certificates for submission and smtp

Tags: postfix, ssl

I have a domain for mua submissions (`smtp.mydomain.com`, Port 587) and one for the inter-server communication (`mail.mydomain.com`, Port 25).

So I'm trying to set `myhostname` for the individual services in `master.cf`:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
    -o myhostname=mail.mydomain.com

smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd

submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
    -o myhostname=smtp.mydomain.com
```

I've set the tls keys like that in `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
```

This setup seems to be working for submission, but the server answers with the cert from `smtp.mydomain.com` when running an ssl check on `mail.mydomain.com`.

I've tried setting the `smtp_tls_cert`, but that didn't help:

```
smtp_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem
smtp_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/privkey.pem
```

Maybe I should set `myhostname=mail.mydomain.com` not on `postscreen` but on `smtpd` for it to work? How do I set the certificates for the smtp service on port 25? Is it even `smtp_tls_cert`?

Comment: did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: @ckujau i'm not actually sure because i didn't verify it properly. But I put the certs for inter-server (port 25) in `main.cf` (`smtpd_tls_cert_file=...`) and set the different certs for submission in `master.cf` in the submission section with `-o smtpd_tls_cert_file=` and `-o smtpd_tls_key_file=`.